# How to show if a series converge absolutely on R when L < 1, but diverges at some points in R if L > 1?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I saw an example of this in practice questions and was wondering how to deal with such questions. given is an random example could someone please explain?

Let R be the square with vertices 0, iL, L, and iL + L. Show that the series.converges absolutely on R when L < 1, but diverges at some points in R if L > 1. Does the series converge on
R when L = 1?
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n z^ne^{-2nz}
$$

Comment: Presumably you mean $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$?

Comment: Let $w=z/e^{2z}.$ The geometric series $\sum_nw^n$ converges if $|w|<1$ and diverges if $|w|\ge 1.$ For $L>0,$ show that $[\, \forall z\in R\,(|w|<1)\,]\iff L<1.$

Comment: @Greg yes ops my bad

Comment: @daniel thanks for that hint does that show the region its converging ? can you please explain a bit more?